# How to add Messenger,Linkedin,Digg,Deleicious in JW player using Share plugins.

Tags: javascript

In my application am using JWplayer Version(4.6.485),i wanna add the following sites Digg,Delicious,Messenger,Linkedin,Google etc in JW player using Sharing plugins.Is it possible to add the above mentioned sites to JW player using sharing plugins.If possible please tell how to add the above mentioned sites in JW player.

Answer (score 0):

You could just position the share buttons over the JWplayer with CSS...